# cambiar src de imagen desde un switch con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

soy nuevo en esto. Estoy haciendo un juego en base texto como los de antes, pero con dos botones donde uno va eligiendo que hacer. Ya pude hacer que cada vez que toques un botón cargue el siguiente texto. Mi idea también es que al tocar el botón cargue una imagen, correspondiente a esa "escena".

```
function juego(){
    switch (state){
        case "Inicio": ui_text.innerHTML = story["Inicio"];
            b1.innerHTML = choice["Inicio"]["boton-1"];
            b2.innerHTML = choice["Inicio"]["boton-2"];
        break;
        case "InicioJuego": ui_text.innerHTML = story["InicioJuego"];
            b1.innerHTML = choice["InicioJuego"]["boton-1"];
            b2.innerHTML = choice["InicioJuego"]["boton-2"];
        break;
    }
}

function boton1Click()
{
    switch(state)
    {
        case "Inicio": state = "InicioJuego";
            break;

        case "InicioJuego": state = "Auto";
            break;
    }
}

function boton2Click()
{
    switch(state)
    {
        case "InicioJuego": state = "Caminar";
            break;  

        case "Caminar": state = "Camino";
            break;
    }
}
```

en html tengo que crear una etiqueta imagen, darle un id y su src.. pero no se como cambiar esos atributos desde js. cualquier idea sera bienvenida, gracias!

Comment: debes agregar un ejemplo minimo verificable y que error te manda!

Comment: esto agregar en el switch document.getElementById('imagenId').src = 'url imagen';

Answer (score 0):

Para esto existe DOM, supongamos que se tiene el siguiente Tag

```
<img id="imagen" />
```

En el Javascript se obtiene la imagen de la siguiente forma:

```
var imagen = documento.getElementById("imagen")
```

Ahora para cambiar o agregar un atributo se hace lo siguiente:

```
imagen.setAttribute("imagen", direccionImagen)
```